# Javascript if statement error with and ('&&')

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find my name in a string, but it appears that JS doesn't accept my `if` statement. It says unexpected token at the first `{`

```
if (text[i] === myName[0] && text.slice(i, i+myName.length === myName){
    for (var j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++)
    {
       hits.push(text[j]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: for future reference you can use sites like http://repl.it/ to lint your javascript this will highlight errors in your code

Comment: @Yahkob that is an awesome site! Thanks. However I'm surprised PHP isn't in the popular section.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If your name is Dan and your name is in the text 3 times you're going to end up with `hits = ['D', 'a', 'n','D', 'a', 'n','D', 'a', 'n']`

Answer (score 2):

Missing closing bracket.

Your `if statement`,

```
if (text[i] === myName[0] && text.slice(i, i+myName.length === myName){
```

Your updated `if statement`,

```
if (text[i] === myName[0] && text.slice(i, i+myName.length === myName)) {
```

Comment: `i+myName.length === myName` --- what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You missed a bracket

```
if (text[i] === myName[0] && text.slice(i, i+myName.length) === myName){ 
                                                       ---^
```

instead of

```
if (text[i] === myName[0] && text.slice(i, i+myName.length === myName){
```